# How can I build a Label in Tkinter containing Text, Emoji Icon and a Link

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to build a label like on the [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xcvK.png) in my GUI. I looked for a solution online, but I couldn't find anything.
I want to use the FontAwesome Heart Icon.

Can you help me please?

My imports:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from pytube import * 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import fontawesome as fa
```

(Maybe some imports are unnecessary)

Comment: Can you update the question with information on what framework you are using to create the GUI.

Comment: Sure, sorry -updated-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to have all three types of values in the same label, but you can split them into 4 different labels. You can make the first three using two lists and creating labels based on the text and colors in the two lists, `words` and `colors`. You can separately make the fourth label, the link, using `.bind()`.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser

def callback(url):
    webbrowser.open_new(url)

words = ["Made with", "❤", "by"]
colors = ["white", "red", "white"]

root = Tk()
for index, word in enumerate(words):
    Label(root, text = word, bg="black", fg=colors[index]).grid(column=index, row=0)
link = Label(root, text = "LINK", font="TKDefaultFont 9 underline", fg = "white", bg = "black", cursor="hand2")
link.grid(column=len(words),row=0)
link.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: callback("https://www.google.com"))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I changed it in my words and placed it in my code. But the problem is, I cant center this text(list) on the bottom 'cause the column are defined with the list. I placed all my Widgets with .place. I can'f figure out how can "convert" it in .place or change the column to the center(for example 5 in a 10x10 grid)

Comment: If you want the center values, you can make the ```row=5```, and set the column in the loop to be: ```column=index+3```.

Comment: Then for the link, you can use column=len(words)+3